# Passing a function in Swift 3

Tags: swift3, closures

One of the drawbacks of a new language is that there often major changes from version to version. As a result anything you find on the Web can easily be out of date. Or maybe it isn't and I just am not reading it correctly.

I'm trying to pass a function in a function call. I can get it to work without any parameters. I just declare the parameter I pass as a class global. Bad experiences in assembler make me want to avoid the dreaded global. Here's the pertinent parts of my working code:

```
class ViewController: NSViewController {
    var artistData: NSArray = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
/*1*/   getDataFromUrl(url: "http://catbox.loc/artists.json", loadFunction: loadArtistTable())
      //getDataFromUrl(url: "http://catbox.loc/artists.json", loadFunction: loadArtistTable)
    }

/*2*/func getDataFromUrl(url: String, loadFunction: ()) {
  //func getDataFromUrl(url: String, loadFunction: (NSArray)) {
  session.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, err in
      do {
          let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableContainers) as? NSArray
          self.artistData = json!
          }
          catch {
              print(error)
          }
/*3*/     loadFunction
        //loadFunction(self.artistData)
      }.resume()
  }
/*4*/ func loadArtistTable() {
//func loadArtistTable(_ jsonData: NSArray) {
    ...
  }
```

The commented out code is one of my many permutations on trying to get it to compile. Ideally, I would like to pass 'json' from the JSONSerialization call. This last attempt was base on the Apple documentation for closure where they gave the example:

```
var reversedNames = names.sorted(by: backward)
```

### My Answer

I've accepted @Nirav D's answer, but I didn't try it. My answer is based on his code. I decided to stick with NSArray. The numbers correspond to the ones I've added to the code above.

```
/*1*/ getDataFromUrl(url: "http://catbox.loc/records.json", loadFunction: loadArtistTable)
/*2*/ func getDataFromUrl(url: String, loadFunction: @escaping (NSArray) ->()) {
/*3*/ loadFunction(json)
/*4*/ func loadArtistTable(jsonData: NSArray) {
```

In 3, I'm using the output of the JSONSerialization directly instead of copying it to a class variable.

### Update

I tried @Nirav D's method and it works as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Swift use Swift's native `Array/Dictionary` instead of `NSArray/NSDictionary`. The way you are looking is called `completionHandler` and pass the function as `completionHandler` when you call the function.

So first make `getDataFromUrl` like this way.

```
func getDataFromUrl(url: String, loadFunction: @escaping ([[String: Any]]?) -> Void) {
    session.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, err in
        var array: [[String:Any]]? = nil
        do {
            if let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableContainers) as? [[String: Any]] {
                 array = json
            }
        }
        catch {
            print(error)
        }
        loadFunction(array)
    }.resume()
}
```

Now create the `loadArtistTable` function

```
func loadArtistTable(array: [[String: Any]]?) {
    if let jsonArray = array { 
        print(array)
    }
}
```

Now simply call your `getDataFromUrl` and pass `loadArtistTable` function as second argument of it.

```
self.getDataFromUrl(url: url, loadFunction: self.loadArtistTable)
```

**Note:** Here `[[String: Any]]` is array of dictionary if you receive array string than create array of `String` like this `[String]`.